# flair image not rendering

Tags: support, status-completed, flair

I understand some people may be really popular (myself) and the flair might stop working. But really, when can you restore my image?

[image: profile for FreshPrinceOfSO on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]

https://stackexchange.com/users/346109/freshprinceofso?tab=flair

Comment: Network flair is served from se.com, which is currently down (bad build). We are working to resolve the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, @Oded.

Comment: @Oded who do we [get to blame](http://jsfiddle.net/AYPpF/82/embedded/result/) this time?